# How can i set a default value in component to a Mat-select triggering (change)

Tags: angular5, angular-material2

Hello i am trying to set a default value in a mat-select with multiple options in the component.ts, and i am managing to do so, but when i set a default value programatically the method that is supposed to execute when the value changes, does not execute, unless i change the value manually, i'm using (change) directive trigger to the method, is there anything else that i can use? like another directive.

I´m using ngModel to set the default value at the moment, setting a value to object.attribute

```
<mat-select [compareWith]="compareBasic" id="object" name="object" 
                    [(ngModel)]="object.attribute" (change)="methodThatIWantToTrigger" class="full-width"
                    required> </mat-select>
```

I should have multiple options in the mat-select, but if there is only one option i want to select that value by default, and i need to know that value that is select in order to get some data from the database. i'm doing something like so:

```
if (this.array.length == 1){ // if it has only one option
        this.object.attribute = this.array[0];
}
```

but this leads to some errors or fails.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 2 way data binding with `[(ngModel)]` you can use `(ngModelChange)` instead of `(change)` . It fires when the value changes.
this is [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whxqma?file=app/select-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Thank you for the help tho, but it is also not working, the method is not getting triggered

Comment: Dcan you show the exact mat-select code part.or stackblitz uploaded one?

Comment: Value should be => [value] and objcect.attribute should be "P" or "T" or "D" same type that bind to value

Comment: Not object.attriburte in this case emitirGuia.tipoInterveniente

Comment: i get what you mean, but in this case, P T and D are an enum, and i cant pass to emitirGuia.tipoInterveniente a string, i have to pass an enum, like im doing in the last piece of code

Comment: Dont't want to pass string.only your object which is set to  a [value] in an option field shoul be equal to the value set to ngModel

Answer (score 0):

It's because mat-select has `selectionChange` event and it's only fired up when `user` change it

> Event emitted when the selected value has been changed by the user.
>   ([angular material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelect))

If you want to emit this `selectionChange` you would have to try with programatically fire event, but you should avoid it. Maybe you can call this method inside your code? Give us your use case, maybe there is a better way.

#### EDIT

Due to your use case, you could go with `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`, so basicly, if you set your default value and you want to be sure, that it is selected in UI you can do something like this. It's a bit hacky, but it will work.

```
if (this.array.length == 1){ // if it has only one option
        this.object.attribute = this.array[0];
        // this will force to refresh value in mat-select
        this.cdr.detectChanges()
        // here you can call your `methodThatIWantToTrigger` becaucse the view is updated.
}
```

Also don't forget to add it in your `constructor` in `component.ts` and import it Change

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';    

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

Comment: i have tried selectionChange before, and it didnt work, i made some edits in my question

Comment: Of course it won't work. because "Event emitted when the selected value has been changed by the user.", but Asanka answer should help you.

Comment: Asanka answer also does not work, the method is not getting triggered

Comment: yes that is kinda what i am doing now, it works sure, but i dont think its the best way of doing it. Im here just to see if there is a better option, maybe there is not.

Comment: Yes, it's hacky solution, but if you change value programatically mat-select won't rise you an event since it's not "user input", you could try to manually fire event on mat-select such as `change` or `click` etc. but it's unstable, because events that `mat-select` is listening can change in future. So the best way is stay with this one, but have you try with `ReactiveForms`? (FormGroup), set control value and subscribe to `valueChanges()` observable, it might work but I'm not sure

Comment: Yes exactly what i though, ill take a look at ReactiveForms tho, thanks for your time.